# minikube start get error: "k8s-app=kube-proxy connection refused"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

On Linux, with minikube `v0.34.1`, when run `minikube start --logtostderr`, get following error:

> I0227 18:25:12.625477   13250 kubernetes.go:121] error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" [Get https://192.168.99.102:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=k8s-app%3Dkube-proxy: dial tcp 192.168.99.102:8443: connect: connection refused]

And, none of following environment variable is set: `$HTTP_PROXY`, `$HTTPS_PROXY`, `$NO_PROXY`.

After searching via google, and checked following posts, still unsolved:

- [minikube may fail with older VM's and apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC: kube-proxy timeout #2948](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2948)
- [HTTP_PROXY set: error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" ... kube-proxy: Service Unavailable #2726](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2726)

Following actions have been tried, with no good news:

- `minikube delete; minikube start`
- `rm -rf ~minikube/`

As a newbie to K8s, really don't understand what this means, any idea ?

---

### @Update - Seems solved

*The solution moved to the answer section*

Comment: you posted a link to some unresolved topic, but are you using an http proxy?

Comment: @c4f4t0r This one is closed: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2948 , the issue is solved by removing the config dir, as I updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the solution posted by [Eric Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568658/eric-wang) from the question to the answer section:

**With following steps seems it's resolved**:

- Make a backup of `~/.minikube/cache/`, optionally.
  Otherwise, will need to download those caches again.
- Removed config & data via `rm -rf ~/.minikube/`
- `mkdir ~/.minikube/`
- Then restore `.minikube/cache/`, if you did a backup.
- `minikube stop`
- `minikube delete`
- `minikube start --logtostderr`

**Tips:**

- The `--logtostderr` flag is useful to get error info on the console.
  Without it, the process can stuck there without giving you any information.